# Do my "slots" each need a separate row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

First, I am making a little raffle site. I have a grid of square buttons (all assigned a number) right now and I want to be able to toggle as many as I want, then send that info to my database that those squares are "taken".

Will I need to make a separate row for each square? Or is there some easier way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to query the db everytime you "toggle" a single square?

Comment: @ShreyasChavan No, just when you click a button

Comment: I have answered your question with an easier structure for your purpose :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case that you want to query the database just when you click a button and not everytime you toggle a square, having a separate record for every number will be unnecessarily expensive. There are more elegant ways of achieving the same result.

I would instead suggest creating a record for individual person playing the raffle with a primary key of autoincrementing id so that you can easily identify a person. Each time a person flips the squares and hit ***submit***, a query will be fired through php that will carry the values entered by that person which will be in form of 0s and 1s. If you have 9 squares for example, the user input will be something like ***101011001***. You can now save the record in form of *< userid  , raffleentry >*. This structure will make it extremely easy for your query system to store the values as well as make out who won the raffle.

Note: You can also do some cheeky stuff and save the raffleentry as a decimal value by interpreting the raffle entry as a binary representation. hence you can save the entry as ***345*** instead of ***101011001***

**EDIT**: To answer OP's question in the comments
*I have a primary key for my users, but I have at least 5 raffles that are going on at one time. Should I make 5 different raffleentry columns? Like raffleentry1, raffleentry2, etc*

You can do that. But again theres a more elegant solution here. Make only a single column (integer) called **raffleentrynumber** this will take values 1-5. Now instead of creating primary key only on the userid, create it one composite *(userid, raffleentrynumber).* What this will do is preserve your primary key integrity constraint and also make your table much cleaner

Your table will look something like

```
USER_ID RAFFLEENTRYNUMBER TICKET
1       1                 101010101
1       2                 111100001
1       3                 000000000     
1       4                 111111111
1       5                 010101010
2       1                 000011110
2       2                 011110011
```

Comment: Really good answer, and I have a primary key for my users, but I have at least 5 raffles that are going on at one time. Should I make 5 different raffleentry columns? Like raffleentry1, raffleentry2, etc.

Comment: I have added the answer as an edit to my previous answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I would create a separate record for every number. I'd also create a second column indicating if they've been selected or not using 0's and 1's. (For example, 1 if it has or 0 if it has not). You can use SQL query statements through php to update these values.